# Find SharePoint View by GUID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have a View GUID in SharePoint that was copied from another file that used the same view. I want to find the original file, but don't know who originally modified the file in SharePoint Designer.

How can I find the View (or page containing the View) that uses a specific GUID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the list still exists on your site, you can find it using the listedit.aspx page with the guid in the url.

The url would look like this

> https://mysite.sharepoint.com/mysitename/mysubsitename/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/listedit.aspx?List=%7Bmyguidgoeshere%7D

Insert your guid between the %7B and %7D

If it is the View Guid that you have, you will need to know the list guid as well, and use the viewedit.aspx page

> https://mysite.sharepoint.com/mysitename/mysubsitename/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/viewedit.aspx?List=%7Bmylistguidgoeshere%7D&View=%7Bmyviewguidgoeshere%7D